# Is there a single line command to do `su`?

Tags: password, username, su

I can do an `su` with `su <username>` and it asks for my password. Is there a password parameter for `su` such that i wont be prompted for a password?

e.g. `su <username> -p <password>`

Comment: It seems the question fits perferctly to superuser: http://superuser.com/  :-)

Comment: You can have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233217/pass-password-to-su-sudo-ssh

or here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715908/how-do-you-make-sudo-save-the-password

Comment: i got it from `superuser` here, http://superuser.com/questions/67765/sudo-with-password-in-one-command-line

Answer (score 14):

If you want to write a script that runs as a different user something like this works, though it dows output the word "password" without a newline to standard out

```
su - username <<!
enterpasswordhere
enter commands to run as the new user
!
```

if you have a user named fred with a password of 1234 and want to get an ls of fred's home directory as fred, without the password string displayed, it would look like

```
su - fred <<! >/dev/null 2>&1
1234
whoami > /dev/tty
ls > /dev/tty
!
```

Comment: hmm, 'standard in must be a tty'

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: Getting Error: `su: must be run from a terminal`.

Comment: Getting `su: Sorry`

Answer (score 7):

I belive, there is not and it would not be a good idea. Here's why:
If you write a password in a command like `su <username> -p <password>`, it would be stored in plain text in your bash history. This is certainly a huge security issue.

If you need to run commands with `su` (or `sudo`) in an automated way, write a shellscript containig the commands without `su` or `sudo` and run `su <username> script.sh`

Comment: `su root script`  still need to enter passwd.

Comment: @DaiKaixian yes, but it is not saved anywhere and nobody can read it

Comment: you can try something like : `echo <passwd> | sudo -S <command-line>`.Althought it is not safe, but it works.

Comment: the whole point of my answer is, that it is not save to write a password in a command. So I advise to *not* do that

Comment: It's only a security issue if you care about the user not being accessed by anyone else. In my case, for example, I just want a new user with no permissions to use for running an external script that I don't trust.

Comment: Just use two blank spaces before executing the command (at the beginning, before the command) and it will not save to history.

Answer (score 0):

This only works for me

`echo "<password>" | sudo -S sleep 1 && sudo su - <username>`

[Original answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1351873/749322)

Comment: Sure, but the password is exposed and that is a hard no ;-) even `cat password.txt | sudo -S` is a better method. At least you can chmod password.txt to read only for the user itself.

Answer (score -4):

If you want to execute some specific commands as a new user, use the following command:
`sudo -u {username} {command to be executed as the new user}`

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The question is about how to handle the password.